# How to precisely control mouse acceleration?

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I swapped to a new mouse and I can't get it to feel right. I've always used slow-medium pointer speed + medium acceleration but I was using my last mouse for like 10 years so I really got used to it.

On the new mouse, I can get the pointer speed right but the acceleration is either too little or too much with the limited settings for it (just slow, medium or fast).

Is there a more precise method of controlling mouse acceleration on win 7? Or perhaps a utility program for it? All I find on the internet is hate for mouse acceleration.

Comment: Try Custom Curve, http://www.esreality.com/post/2363191/custom-mouse-accel-program-for-windows/ **N.B.** This question and comment really belong in Software Recommendations, so I move to close it.

Comment: Custom Curve definitely achieves this! It even works to "abuse" it to create a custom mouse speed, beyond the annoyingly restricted slider.

@DrMoishe Pippik This is not purely a question for a software recommendation, what they asked for can be done even by pure hex value editing in the registry. And they asked "how to...", and not "what program..."

Answer (score 1):

I need mouse acceleration because I run up to four monitors at once, one 4K. But I have to turn it off when I work in Photoshop or play a sniper in Overwatch.

So I found some simple utility that lets me turn mouse acceleration off and on by clicking its icon in the system tray:

**[Mouse Accelerator for Windows](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Mouse-Accelerator.shtml)**
Enable or disable mouse acceleration at any time by simply clicking a system tray icon, with the help of this tiny, open-source program

This is a simple exe with no installer, I just dropped it in a folder and added a symlink (shortcut) to it in the Startup folder, which these days is located at:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
```

[image]

Simple system tray icon, clicking toggles acceleration, context menu contains only "Exit"

This is for any version of Windows.

Works adequately for me.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/947228)

Comment: Working on it. For some reason the image is showing up only as a hyperlink and the alt text.

Comment: I fixed the image for you! Good work on the answer!

Comment: Thanks! You can't actually include a caption for the image or it shows that *instead* of the image? That's not only problematic, but unclear from the instructions/interface for uploading the image.

Comment: You can use alt text but it won't show the caption automatically for sighted people. One of the few occasions that accessibility users have it better! You may have also had issueswith embedding the image as you are a new user. You should be OK now.

Comment: Well, a new user on here, but I've been on stackexchange forever. I'm surprised there isn't a unified login, like wikimedia, or at least something like oAuth to share logins.

Comment: Actually, I guess it's a unified account, but doesn't share reputation between the sites? Still seems disappointing.